# How to save a rendered view to file with Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My website has an RSS feed with a route http://example.com/rss

I have now to provide a feed for Outbrain, and they need a feed with about 5000 contents. I can provide the feed "live" but I choose to add a task scheduled with whenever to save my feed offline in the public folder. Every night I will update the feed.

I add a class method to my content class...

```
def self.render_outbrain
    data = render_to_string( :controller=>:NewsFeedController, :action => :outbrain )
    File.open('outbrain.xml','w'){|f| f << data }
  end
```

But it doesn't work in Rails 4.2:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `render_to_string' for main:Object
```

I want to save the output of http://example.com/rss to a static file http://example.com/feed.rss

Edit

Here is my task:

```
task :generate_feed_rake => :environment do
  session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
  session.get "/generate_feed"
end
```

Here is my controller

```
  def generate_feed

    # the news items
    @items = Content.published.limit(1000)

    # this will be our Feed's update timestamp
    @updated = @items.first.updated_at unless @items.empty?

    respond_to do |format|
      format.atom { render :layout => false }
      format.rss { redirect_to feed_path(:format => :atom), :status => :moved_permanently }
    end   

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

`render_to_string` is defined in `ActionController::Base`.  Unless your class inherits from that class, it makes sense that your object doesn't know how to `render_to_string`.

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but the way `render_to_string` works is, in a controller, instead of rendering an HTML view for the browser, you simply send back the HTML as a string

Comment: so I can move everything inside my controller?

Comment: I'm adding some details.
I have a task.
This task call my controller.
My controller instead of render the view must "write" the view to a file.